# C# extract html values to list using linq

Tags: c#, html, list, linq, web

I am definitely new to C# and especially the HtmlAgilityPack and linq but I am trying to put together a linq statement to retrieve particular values from an html page within certain fields. This is the link statement I am working with:

```
List<testClass> Results = (from div in doc1.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")                                      
                                   from c in div.Descendants("class")
                                   select new testClass(
                                              c.Attributes["hdp-fact-ataglance-heading"].Value,
                                              c.Attributes["hdp-fact-ataglance-value"].Value
                                              )).ToList();
```

It is not working correctly and I dont know why, I want it to put the values into a list that I can read to the screen. Unfortunately, I get a blank list with 0 values. The linq reads as correct in the debugger and I get 0 errors. The main thing I want to do is avoid using any loops for performance purposes. I believe I am not selecting the correct nodes or not getting the linq together right. This is a snippet of the HTML:

```
    <div class="hdp-fact-category">Bedrooms</div>
    <ul class="zsg-sm-1-1 hdp-fact-list" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1499723568429_1169">
        <li class="" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1499723568429_1168">
            <span class="hdp-fact-name">Beds: </span>
            <span class="hdp-fact-value" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1499723568429_1167">4</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="hdp-fact-container" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1499723568429_2392">
    <div class="hdp-fact-category">Heating and Cooling</div>
    <ul class="zsg-sm-1-1 hdp-fact-list" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1499723568429_2391">
        <li class="">
            <span class="hdp-fact-name">Heating: </span>
            <span class="hdp-fact-value">Forced air</span>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1499723568429_2390">
            <span class="hdp-fact-name">Cooling: </span>
            <span class="hdp-fact-value">Central</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="hdp-fact-container">
    <div class="hdp-fact-category">Basement</div>
    <ul class="zsg-sm-1-1 hdp-fact-list">
        <li class="">
            <span class="hdp-fact-value">Unfinished basement</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am ultimately trying to get the console output like this using the usual loop and console.writeline(list[i]):
Beds: 4

heating: forced air

etc. I only want to use this particular loop to check the loop contents (its not permanent)

As of now I am using this to extract my data.... to say the least it takes a very long time. Which is why I was attempting to use linq as I thought maybe it would be faster? I dont know the best approach any recommendations would be appreciated.

```
public string searchSCH(string content, string starttag, string endtag, int count)
    {
        string contentsub;
        int location1, location2;
        location1 = location2 = 0;
        if (content.Contains(starttag))
        {
            do
            {
                location1 = content.IndexOf(starttag, location1 + 1);
                if (location1 == -1)
                    return null;

                count--;
            } while (count > 0);

            location2 = content.IndexOf(endtag, location1 + 1);
            if (location2 == -1)
                return null;

            location1 += starttag.Length;
            contentsub = content.Substring(location1, location2 - location1);

            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim();
            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, "\".*>", string.Empty).Trim();
            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, "  ", "%");
            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, "\n", string.Empty);
            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, "\r", string.Empty);
            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, "\">", string.Empty);
            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, "\"%.*>", string.Empty);
            contentsub = Regex.Replace(contentsub, @"%+", "|");
            return contentsub;
        }
        else
        {
            return "fail";
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can't just say 'It is not working correctly' and expect us to know how to solve it... tell us how it is not working.... Do you get an error? Not expected results? If not - What results DO you get?

Comment: My apologies, There are no errors in debug. I get no values into the list.

Comment: not sure if you could filter children by using class which is not tag but a attribute here div.Descendants("class")

Answer (score 0):

Break your logic up into smaller pieces:

```
//This should give you a list of all the containers
var nodes = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'hdp-fact-container')]");

//Then loop through each container to grab the category ("hdp-fact-category")
//and the facts list ("hdp-fact-list")
foreach(var item in nodes)
{
    var categoryNode = item.SelectNode("//div[contains(@class, 'hdp-fact-category']");
    var factsList = item.SelectNodes("//ul[contains(@class, 'hdp-fact-list')]/li");

    //Then do whatever with those nodes
}
```

I based my answer on the assumption that you would want the "Category" too.  If you do not, then just exclude that expression.

Comment: Do you know of a way to avoid using loops to do extract the desired data? I'm dealing with about 1.4mil html files.

Comment: @Wes your original solution was using LINQ, what do you think some of those operators do internally?  Have you tried my solution to see how it performs with your data?  There isn't a whole lot of optimizing you can do when parsing HTML/XML, you are at the mercy of the document size.

Comment: My apologies I didnt mean to imply that the linq was not looping. I was just wondering if you knew of a way to extract the desired data without loops being involved as you are more knowledgeable than I. I unfortunately was unable to get the code above to work.

Comment: Well you have multiple items that you need to process, thats exactly what loops are designed for.  What is your apprehension to using loops?  Also, what specifically didn't work with my code?

Comment: I got this error System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: ''//div[contains(@class, 'hdp-fact-list']' has an invalid token.'
I am unfamiliar with XPath, are there certain constraints to using XPath that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Wes I updated my code a while ago because I saw an error. Try it again